# Why does Python Flask throw a HTTP 404 error

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

It is several years since I have used Flask, starting on a new project.
I get a HTTP 404 error. The requested URL is not found??

The index and the requested URL are both in the templates folder.
I don't understand why it is throwing a **HTTP 404 error**??

Any pointers appreciated, thanks.

Clive

I have a code snippet in routes.py.

```
@app.route('/service_response', methods=['GET','POST'])
def service_response():
  servicesql = "SELECT * FROM DASHBOARD_SERVICE_RESPONSE"
  data = list(conn.execute(servicesql))
      
  return render_template('service_response.html', service_response=servicesql)
```

In index.html I have:

```
<div class="form chartdisplay" >
    <div class="form-heading">BCC Report Period</div>   
        <br>
        <div class="form-group"; class="height-auto";>  
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <iframe src="service_response.html" width="90%" height="90%"></iframe>
                </thead>            
            </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code points to `src="service_response.html"` while what you want to do is to point to `/service_response` which will render the 'service_response.html' jinja template.